# Use awk to replace one column value with another column value if the first letter is not a alphabet letter

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following csv file:

```
ID                Name          Gender        NID
Y12               Jim              M          C12
Y23               David            M          C23
234               Bob              M          C22
2b1               Lucy             F          C24
2bb               Lily             F          C25
```

What I want to do is to replace ID colunm's value with NID value if the first letter in ID is not a alphabet letter.
So the output is expected to be

```
ID                Name          Gender        NID
Y12               Jim              M          C12
Y23               David            M          C23
C22               Bob              M          C22
C24               Lucy             F          C24
C25               Lily             F          C25
```

This is just a sample. My original data size is much bigger so I have to use `awk`. The key issue is how to specify the condition. I am not clear how to deal with. 
The code I was thinking of is like `awk -F, 'if $1 != ..., $1=$4'`. I also googled but failed to find an appropriate solution. 
Here is a link which I think may be helpful. 
[Filter lines that have only alphabets in first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581354/filter-lines-that-have-only-alphabets-in-first-column). Thank you.

Comment: Your input isn't csv, did you copy the wrong text?

Comment: It's just an example. My real data is very large so I cannot post it here. I guess if it's csv file, separated by ",", then we only need to write  ``` awk -F,``` ,  which can help  ```awk```  to recognize the csv file.

Comment: You can, in this case. But you are better to post a more representative sample of your data and output as it may change the answers people give.

Comment: Okay. I will first apply those posted solutions into my original data to see whether they do work. If not, then I will post a sample from my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[^A-Z]/ { $1 = $4 }1' filename
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/lo3AV0)

Comment: @Samson Did you leave out the `1` at the end?

Comment: @Samson, I found the Grymoire tutorials very useful when I was learing - http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: @Barmar Hi, there is another sub-issue. I found that such code could not help me to distinguish whether the first letter is uppercase or not. As long as the first letter is alphabet, then ID will be replaced by NID. What if I only want to change ID with uppercase?

Comment: My code is case-sensitive, it only keeps the ID if it begins with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Anyway, change `A-Z` to `A-Za-z` if you want to treat uppercase and lowercase letters similarly.

Comment: @Samson to learn AWK get the book "Effective AWK Programming", 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Don't get any other book as the rest are outdated and/or worse in other ways. To test for upper case use the [Character Class inside a Bracket Expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) `[[:upper:]]` rather than `[A-Z]` (the latter won't work in every locale, the former will), for lower `[[:lower:]]` and for either `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: For case sensitive letters you can use awk '$1 ~ /^[^[Aa]-[Zz]]/ { $1 = $4 }1' filename

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on the ID column always being 3 characters, this will preserve the table formatting:

```
awk '{ sub("^[^[:alpha:]]..", $4) } 1' file
```